# Convert PostgreSQL nested JSON to numeric array in Tableau

Tags: database, postgresql, data-science, tableau-api, postgresql-json

I have a PostgreSQL database containing a table `test_table` with individual records. First column is a simple `store_id`, second column `meausurement` is a nested json.

```
store_id | measurement
----------------------
0        | {...}
```

The format of the `measurement` column is as follows:

```
{
    'file_info': 'xxxx', 
    'data': {
        'contour_data': {
            'X': [-97.0, -97.0, -97.0, -97.0, -97.0, -97.0],
            'Y': [-43.0, -41.0, -39.0, -39.0, -38.0, -36.0]
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to plot `Y` vs. `X` in a scatter plot in Tableau. Therefore I connected the database successfully with the PostgreSQL connector of Tableau. From [this](https://community.tableau.com/ideas/6294) page I learned, that I have to use Custom SQL queries to extract data from the json object, since Tableau doesn't directly support the `json` datatype of Postgres. I tried already the following Custom SQL Query in Tableau:

```
select
    store_id as store_id,
    measurement#>>'{data, contour_data, X}' as contour_points_x,
    measurement#>>'{data, contour_data, Y}' as contour_points_y
from test_table
```

which successfully extracts the two arrays to two new columns `contour_points_x` and `contour_points_y`. However both new columns are in Tableau of type `string`, so I cannot use them as data source for a plot.

How do I have to adjust the Custom SQL query to make the data arrays plottable in a Tableau scatter plot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is a concatenation of several functions and/or syntax operations. One has to

- use the [`#>`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) operator to dig in the `json` and return it **as `json` type** (not as `text` type as `>>#` does).
- use [`json_array_elements_text()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) to expand the `json` to a set of `text`.
- use type cast operator `::` to convert `text` to `float`

```
/* custom SQL Query in Tableau */
select 
    store_id as store_id,
    json_array_elements_text(measurement#>'{data, contour_data, X}')::float as contour_points_x,
    json_array_elements_text(measurement#>'{data, contour_data, Y}')::float as contour_points_y,
from test_table
```

Both resulting columns appear in a Tableau Sheet now as discrete measures. Changing to discrete dimensions allows to plot `contour_points_y` vs. `contour_points_x` as desired.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to split the columns. Check this https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/split.htm

EDIT - the linked approach works when you can reliably assume an upper bound for the number of points in each list. One way to split arbitrarily sized lists is described here https://apogeeintegration.com/blog/apogee-busts-out-multi-value-cells-using-tableau-prep-builder

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. However, while this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.